# Attach and modify Content Children as Component property

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I'm trying to attach data to a Component from its light DOM children and modify them a bit in Angular 2.

```
<buttons>
   <button value="male">Male</button>
   <button value="female">Female</button>
</buttons>
```

**buttons.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'buttons',
   templateURL: './buttons.component.html'
})

export class ButtonsComponent {
   //buttons: array of buttons
   selectButton(index): void {
      console.log(this.buttons[index]);
   }
}
```

**buttons array entry**

```
{
   label: HTMLButtonELement.textContent,
   value: HTMLButtonELement.value
}
```

**buttons.component.html**

```
<button *ngFor+="let button of buttons; let i = index"
   id="{{i}}" value="{{button.value}}" 
   (click)="selectButton({{buttons[i]}})">
   {{button.label}}
</button>
```

Comment: @Surreal How can I assign the 'buttons' property to the ButtonsComponent class the way I want to?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @Faisal A resuable component, which can be used as a form input, tabs controller and more

Comment: you need @ContentChildren query

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi I've tried so, but when I add 
"@ContentChildren(ElementRef) buttons"
to my class the 'buttons' property becomes a QueryList and not a modified array as I want it to be

Comment: what do you mean modifying array? why do you need it to be modifyiable?